# Extend a dataframe with values and next dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have to following dataframe:

```
        value        time
1  177.059998  2022-05-13
```

And this array of numbers:

```
[[192.62466]
 [189.60422]
 [186.8717 ]
 [191.22443]]
```

I want to create new rows in the dataframe with this values and forward date values like so:

```
        value        time
1  177.059998  2022-05-13
2  192.62466   2022-05-14
3  189.60422   2022-05-15
4  186.8717    2022-05-16
5  191.22443   2022-05-17
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
# Assuming 'time' column is a DatetimeIndex
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'value': np.array(m).flatten(),
                    'time': pd.date_range(df['time'].max(), periods=len(m)+1, 
                                          freq='D', inclusive='right')})

out = pd.concat([df, df1], ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
        value       time
0  177.059998 2022-05-13
1  192.624660 2022-05-14
2  189.604220 2022-05-15
3  186.871700 2022-05-16
4  191.224430 2022-05-17
```

Comment: could you name what is "m" in "np.array(m).flatten()" and "periods=len(m)+1"?

Comment: `m` is your array of numbers.

Comment: `_generate_range() got an unexpected keyword argument 'inclusive'`

Comment: I was in an older version, upgraded to 1.4 as shown in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html). Working now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Value': [1,2,3,4,5]}
data=pd.DataFrame(data=data)
data1=pd.date_range(start='2022-05-13',end='2022-05-17',name='date')
data1=pd.DataFrame(data=data1)
pd.concat([data,data1], axis=1)
```

result

```
    Value   date
0   1   2022-05-13
1   2   2022-05-14
2   3   2022-05-15
3   4   2022-05-16
4   5   2022-05-17
```